# Updating JSON data on my web page without needing to reload the page

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch-api, reload

I am trying to make a photo album where there are some authors with their descriptions. I can add a new author, update an existing author, or reset the gallery to deafult. I use the fetch API to update, submit or reset data via forms. And to display the data, I again use a fetch GET request to receive JSON data from the server with authors to fill my album. However, my problem is whenever I update my album, I have to refresh the whole page for the updated data to be visible on the web page. How can I do this without user having to reload the whole page?

I have found solutions where they use AJAX or jQuery, but nothing seems to be working with my project. Is there any other way?

```js
form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    fetch('myUrl', {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            image: new FormData(form).get('image'),
            author: new FormData(form).get('author'),
            alt: new FormData(form).get('alt'),
            tags: new FormData(form).get('tags'),
            description: new FormData(form).get('description')
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: Try making the function `async` and `await`ing the `fetch` request.

Comment: It still doesnt work, and my instructer told me not to use async functions here.

Comment: You need to make AJAX requests but are not allowed to use async functions? That's an odd requirement. How about `fetch(...).then(...)`?

Comment: how can I achieve this with fetch .then?

Comment: Here are some examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch